# How can I cheat (I know, I know) Enforcer Police Crime Action on mac?

Tags: macos, cheats, enforcer-police-crime-action

I have just bought "Enforcer: Police, Crime, Action" from the Mac App Store, and whilst it is a mediocre game, I feel it would be better with some... help.

I've been told by many a Windows counterpart that they are able to edit the .XML file and give themselves money and other things of the sort. How can I do this on a Mac?

I looked in `~/Library/Application Support` but it wasn't there...

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?  If there's something specific you want to do, we work better with precise focuses.

Comment: Trying to do the equivalent of editing the XML file. This allows me to change values such as how much my stress level deteriorates by, how quickly I regain health, and how much money I have.

Comment: Ask your windows friends what is the name of the XML file, make a search for it on your mac, edit it?

Comment: Their .xml file is in AppData>LocalLow>OdinGameStudio>Enforcer>DATA_Saves, but AppData doesn't exist on mac.

Comment: I've also looked in ~/Library/Application Support/ and there was nothing there by the name of "Enforcer"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not follow the rule of "problem dependant on the video game aspect"; asker is asking how to edit XML files on a mac. While they are wanting to do so for the purpose of a game, the topic is not (itself) game-related. Perhaps this would be a better question for SuperUser?

Comment: It is a Mac-specific question, so I'd recommend it for Ask Different.

Answer (score 1):

Application data for apps purchased *from the Mac App Store* goes in ~/Library/Containers/, not ~/Library/Application Support/. Check there.

Answer (score 0):

I opened up finder and did command shift g and pasted~/Library/Application Support and found `unity.OdinGameStudio.Enforcer/` and I searched around and found a file. I opened the first one and opened safari so I closed it and right clicked on it and open with text editor or whatever and I could edit my gender name money ex and stuff.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which file it is.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
You have to:
1) "Go" in the status bar - Hold Alt - Library
2) Containers - unity.OdinGameStudio.EnforcerPoliceCrimeAction - Data - Library - Application Support - unity.OdinGameStudio.EnforcerPoliceCrimeAction - DATA_saves 
3) This folder gives you the .xml files - edit them w/ xcode, it's easier.
4) just change the numbers and save :)

Done!

Answer (score -2):

I found mine under:
~/Library/Application Support/unity.OdinGameStudio.Enforcer/

Hope this helps.